# How to get coordinates of an image/JLabel?

Tags: java, image, coordinates, jlabel

I have a game which contains a player which is a basket and fruit falling the main point is to catch the fruit. I tried getting coordinates and location of fruit but I can't get it to work.
any help?

This is the code which I use to try and get coordinates but this isn't working since .getMinX will always be zero and .getMinY.. I need another way of getting coordinations or fruit image.

```
public static void checkCollision(BufferedImage player)
    {
        double fruitOneLocation = image.getMinX() & image.getMinY();
        double playerLocation = player.getMinX() & player.getMinY();
```

Comment: I presume you must be drawing these images, and there must be logic in your code which defines where they are drawn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing a game, your player (and other game objects) can't just be represented by Image-objects. You should write your own classes for this.

Here's an example:

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Player {
  //X- and Y-Coordinates
  public int x,y;

  //Player graphic
  Image img=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("path.to.your.image.file");

  public Player(){

  }
  //Rendering method
  //You should call this in your frame class where you override paint(Graphics g)
  //or paintComponent(Graphics g)
  //
  //like this: player.draw(g,this)
  public void draw(Graphics g,JPanel jp){
    //Draw the Image at the right position
    g.drawImage(img,x,y,jp);
  }

  //Get X coordinate
  public int getX(){
    return x;
  }

  //Get Y coordinate
  public int getY(){
    return y;
  }

  //Update method
  //You should call this in your game loop
  public void update(){
    //Handle button presses, collision testing or other stuff relating
    //the player object here
  }
```

}

As you can see, you have direct access and control over the player's coordinates. You should write a class like this for all of your game's objects.